# for callback, passing channels as data through other channels

Tags: go, channel

I am trying to include a channel to a struct as a member. An instance of the struct will be processed step by step when being passed to different goroutines over channels by an initiator (there going to be multiple initiators concurrently). 
And the channel member will be used as callback which returns the outcome of each step to the initiator.

So, is it a good practice passing channels as data through other channels?
Shall I use the pointer of the channel instead?
Any other patterns recommend?

=================Some additional thoughts==============

Compare to have a global sync.Map mapping initiators to callback channels for each goroutines to lookup, shall I actually send the callback channel over channels?

Comment: There's no reason to use the pointer of a channel, unless you need a receiver to be able to modify it. Other than that, whether it's a good approach to send channels over channels is a matter of opinion and/or implementation.

Comment: @Flimzy Thank you! Okay, I don't think I want a receiver to modify the callback channel. So, no pointer.

Comment: @Flimzy As to whether it's a good approach, would you explain more on the opinions and/or implementations you mentioned?

Comment: No, that topic is far too broad to be covered in a comment, and off-topic for a question/answer. A better approach is to explain your actual goal, rather than speaking in broad abstractions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not a bad practice. It’s perfectly OK to pass a channel through another channel and use it to collect result.

Note that what you describe is not exactly a callback since the go routine doesn’t call anything. It simply write data in the channel transmitted through the channel.

If you passed a function in the channel and the go routine would call it, then you would have a callback.